# How to Write Values from NSDictionary to XMLDocument?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, nsxmldocument

I need to create an XML file using a pre-defined schema and the XML nodes must be populated from values in `NSDictionary`.  The document must then be stored in the local file system for upload.

After creating a new instance of `XMLDocument`in my View Controller, how do I read values from NSDictionary Submission and write them to an XML document in my file system?

Comment: do you want an xml file representing the schema model, or do you want to export the data that is in the database?

Comment: I want to export the data into an XML file from the database.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  You can get the data using a `NSFetchRequest`, then create a `NSXMLDocument` and save the data to a file using `NSFileManager`.  Do you have code that is not working?

Comment: @JonRose I'm having trouble with obtaining stored values from my NSDictionary object and writing them into nodes of the XML Document.